# How can I print the id of the newly created discord text channel?

Tags: python, discord, channel

I am super new at python and discord. The code below works to create a new channel when a user types $create. I just need to somehow get the channel id for the newly created channel and print it on my terminal. Please help....

```
@bot.command(name='create')
async def create_channel(ctx, channel_name='New-temporary'):
    name = 'ideas'  # this name is for which channel to put it in
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    guild = ctx.guild
    print(guild)
    print(f'Creating a new channel: {channel_name}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name, category=category)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_text_channel` will return the channel that was just created. You can get the id as follows:

```
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name, category=category)
print(channel.id)
```